# Creating a Java program for a budget

Tags: java, netbeans, operators, multiplication, addition

I'm trying to create a java program in netbeans for a simple budget that will include 2 multiplication and  1 addition operators. I need it to accept three different amount put in by the user. Right now I have:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of days you will be traveling: ");
int number1 = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the cost of your hotel per day: ");
int number2 = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter the number of miles you will travel over the entire trip: ");
int number3 = input.nextInt();

int multiplication = number1 * number2
System.out.printf("The total price of your hotel for your trip is *d*n.", number1, number2);
```

I need to add a multiplication operator to multiple the number of miles by .78 cent but I'm not sure how to do that or format in a way that shows dollar or cents with 2 decimals and I'm not sure if its similar to the way html formats decimals. And lastly I need to add the miles*.78 to the total for the hotel per day.

So far I have what is above but ive added "int multiplication = number3 * .78" which I dont think is going to work but I dont have a good example of a correct way to multiply a number from input with a decimal already in the program. And then I'm not sure how to use a result from the first operator in a addition operator. I don't think I need if, else statements but I'm not sure.

Comment: Correct.  That won't work.  Ask yourself: "what is the type of `number3 * .78`"?  And why are you assigning it to an `int` variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what variable to assign it because that is the only example I've been given in class and the chapter we've gone over. But I've changed them to int numberDays, int hotelPrice, and int numberMiles. I put in another variable int pricePerMile = .78 (Do I use double instead? "double numberDays = input.nextInt();). I'm still unsure of how to format too because it wasnt taught either. I've looked at examples online but I'm not sure how to implement it in my situation or where.

Comment: Please just ask one question at a time.  From what I can make out, you are asking 3 or 4 different things in the above.  Also, it is better if you try to find answers from your lecture notes, text book, tutorial or whatever.  And don't just look at the examples.  Read the text descriptions as well ... where they explain things. You will learn more ... and probably quicker ... by doing that.

Comment: The chapters I'm supposed to go off of doesn't include any variable types except Int. It also doesn't include how to format with decimals

Comment: Well ... then ... you need to talk to your teacher ... if you think that you need *permission* to "go off" other chapters.  When you multiply something by `0.78` the number won't be an integer anymore.  You need to understand the basics of floating point numbers in Java in order to do this exercise.  Get your (ahem) "teacher's permission", and then read about it.   (Or think about what it means mathematically to multiply by 0.78.)

Comment: Well in the book it mentions this site specifically can be used for questions. So what I'm trying to clarify now is, can I use "double numberDays" for a users input and would that still be = input.nextInt();.

Comment: 1) Yes you can.  2) That's a pretty crap book if they are suggesting to use / abuse StackOverflow as a free teaching service!!

Comment: Its 'Java How to program 11th edition'. It mentions float and double once but only gives examples of variable declarations with integers which helped for the first part of my homework but not this project. It also explains different operators but only really goes into depth and gives example of addition mostly. I would think stackoverflow is used to help teach so I wouldn't call it abuse.

Comment: Well I would.  StackOverflow is a Q&A site and not a teaching site.  It is crystal clear from the Tour.   But regarding the book talking about `float` and `double` but only giving `int` examples ... I think that illustrates what I was saying about the importance of reading (and understanding) the text.  And ... also ... a book doesn't "teach" either ... and they certainly there is no *requirement* that you must do things linearly; e.g. only using things that you have been "taught already".  You don't anyone's permission.  There are no rules when you are self teaching.